# Is there data on the most common password strength requirements?

Tags: passwords, password-policy

Many websites have different requirements for a strong password (beyond simple length I mean). Anecdotally, I think these requirements are common:

- Password must contain a mix of upper and lower case letters
- Password must contain at least one number
- Password must contain a special character like `()*&^%$£"-` etc.
- Password must be longer than 8 characters

I'm wondering what the most common requirements set by everyday websites are. Obviously this is impossible to answer definitively given the number of websites on the internet, but I'm wondering whether anyone has collected some amount of data gathering the modal password strength requirements? I was not able to find this from Googling.

Comment: If you are looking at examples of dumb password rules and things to avoid, there is a fantastic repository for this at https://github.com/dumb-password-rules/dumb-password-rules Two research articles of note are: - [Testing metrics for password creation policies by attacking large sets of revealed passwords (2010)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1866307.1866327) - [Of passwords and people: measuring the effect of password-composition policies (2011)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1978942.1979321)

Answer (score 3):

> ... but I'm wondering whether anyone has collected some amount of data gathering the modal password strength requirements?

[A Second Look at Password Composition Policies
in the Wild: Comparing Samples
from 2010 and 2016](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/soups2017/soups2017-mayer.pdf) from Usenix 2017 has collected password policies and strength requirements from many web sites. In this paper you'll find also links to related papers.